# Can a single case entail the execution of multiple cases?

Tags: go, switch-statement

I want to execute case `'b'` and case `'c'` for case `'a'`:

```
foo := 'a'
switch foo {
case 'a':
    // execute both case 'b' and case 'c'
case 'b':
    // only execute case 'b'
case 'c':
    // only execute case 'c'
}
```

I have tried to fallthrough case `'a'` into case `'b'` and then fallthrough case `'b'` into case `'c'` if `foo == 'a'`, however conditional fallthrough statements are not allowed and they will throw a `"fallthrough statement out of place"` error.

This problem can be solved by copying the code from both case `'b'` and case `'c'` into case `'a'` and can also be solved by using other methods of conditional branching besides switch statements, however I am wondering if there is a solution to this problem using switch statements and without copying code between cases to achieve a similar result.

Comment: I think it's better to use if-else rather switch in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

```golang
if foo == 'a' || foo == 'b' {
    // case 'b'
}
if foo == 'a' || foo == 'c' {
    // case 'c'
}
```

```golang
switch foo {
case 'a':
    b()
    c()
case 'b':
    b()
case 'c':
    c()
}

func b() { /* ... */ }
func c() { /* ... */ }
```